# z-index(?) problem while reviewing

Tags: bug, theme

Some elements of the underlying page are visible inside the "review box" at the top of the page while reviewing.

[image]

Comment: Reproducible in Firefox 72.0.2

Comment: I wonder if I need to post this to meta.stackoverflow.com or meta.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Staff are supposed to monitor [tag:bug] reports anywhere so migrating isn't encouraged. That said, perhaps it is related to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344041/tags-tabs-and-the-timeline-button-flow-over-review-info-panels-when-scrolling

Comment: @PaulWhite9 Thanks, looks very similar.